# Joining two tables on multiple columns and subtracting the value field

Tags: sql, join, key, subtraction

I have two tables, Table_A and Table_B both having the same number of columns and structure, without having any unique key in any of them. They have one single value field. I would like to subtract the value in Table_B from Table_A, as if I was doing a lookup/match in SQL.

Table_A:
| Foo     | Bar     | Baz       | Units      |
| ------- | ------- | --------- | ---------- |
| Foob    | Barz    | Bazr      | 6          |
| Foor    | Barr    | Bazz      | 5          |
| Fooz    | Barz    | Bazz      | 4          |

Table_B:
| Foo     | Bar     | Baz       | Units      |
| ------- | ------- | --------- | ---------- |
| Foob    | Barz    | Bazr      | 3          |
| Foor    | Barr    | Bazz      | 2          |
| Fooz    | Barz    | Bazz      | 2          |

Result:
| Foo     | Bar     | Baz       | Units      |
| ------- | ------- | --------- | ---------- |
| Foob    | Barz    | Bazr      | 2          |
| Foor    | Barr    | Bazz      | 4          |
| Fooz    | Barz    | Bazz      | 2          |

I would like to arrive at the Result table as seen above, as if I had a unique key that is the combination of Foo-Bar-Baz. The two tables are created in a way that there are no duplicate Foo-Bar-Baz combinations in either A or B. Although there are Foo-Bar-Baz combinations that either exist in only one table or the other.

This might not be the best way to use SQL but it would make my life easier if I could execute it in one script.

I was joining the two tables, such as below, but it gave me duplications:

```
SELECT A.Foo, A.Bar, A.Baz, A.Units-B.Units
FROM Table_A
FULL JOIN Table_B ON A.Foo=B.Foo AND A.Bar=B.Bar AND A.Baz=B.Baz;
```

Comment: I'd rather expect syntax error. (Try AND, not comma, between the conditions.)

Comment: Tag your particular database - your sql would give an error on every database I've used.

Comment: You were right, I did mess up the syntax here, it was working in my database. The problem was not even this code, but the fact that Table_A and Table_B were not aggregated right (they were temp tables, group by those 3 descriptive columns, but there the code was not working...) I really appreciate the quick help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for a `GROUP BY` instead of `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

`UNION ALL` the tables, use negative SUM values for TABLE_B. `GROUP BY` the result.

```
SELECT Foo, Bar, Baz, SUM(Units)
FROM
(
  SELECT Foo, Bar, Baz, Units
  FROM Table_A
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Foo, Bar, Baz, -Units
  FROM Table_B
) dt
GROUP BY Foo, Bar, Baz
```

Comment: Omg, what a neat trick to use -Units... much cleaner! Thanks!